# Auto follow back on Twitter using Twython

Tags: python, raspbian, twython

I have set up an auto tweet bot with auto follow back.
I have noticed after about a week the auto follow back on the script stops working.

```
    try:
        followers = api.get_followers_ids(screen_name = "Twitter Handle goes here")
        for followers_ids in followers['ids']:
            api.create_friendship(user_id=followers_ids)
    except TwythonError as e:
        print(e)
```

The error code doesnt print anything, so I cant tell whats happening.

Is there possibly a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it turns out the code runs fine I was just running an older version that wasnt setup correctly.

I would still like to know If there is a quicker way to do this though, I have tried a few different ways and none of them have even worked.

Full source code for the bot [here](https://github.com/theferris/Rising-Spin-Bot-Source) if anyones interested.